# can someone help me when i send this form i get the php displayed instead of it executed the php code

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

when ever i try to setup a html form that send the information over to mysql the php code is always displayed instead of being executed here is my code can someone please explain where i am going wrong spent week trolling the internet looking for a answer and still haven't got any further on in my work

html form page:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
students name: <input type="text" name="studentsname">
students form: <input type="text" name="studentsform">
teachers id: <input type="text" name="teachersid">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

now this next bit is the code for mysql database

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","onduty");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO on duty request (studentsname, studentsform, teachersid)
VALUES
('$_POST[studentsname]','$_POST[studentsform]','$_POST[teachersid]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

i could really use someones help to explain to me why the php code is being displayed instead of being executed
thanks 
daniel

Comment: If your browser is showing the full contents of the `insert.php` file, then it doesn't have php correctly installed.

Comment: is the `form` and the `insert.php` code in the same file?

Comment: and yes the form file and insert.php are in their own folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script is not running and you are seeing php code in your browser it sounds like your web server is not configured correctly.

Could be many things; needs more information. What web server are you running, what version of php is installed, is php installed correctly, etc.

Comment: ok so how would i configure my browser(safari) to run the php code

Comment: @Daniel Not the browser; the web server where your code is stored.

Comment: i dont know what version of php i am running but my browser is up to date and i am using the latest version of text wrangler

Comment: a i am using mysql and everything should be uptodate i am using localhost and i am running it through myphpadmin

Comment: @daniel Sounds like you are running on Mac? Do you have php enabled in your apache config?  Try following the steps on this page http://php.about.com/od/phpbasics/ss/installMac_2.htm

Comment: just dont that and when i got to the bit to # there allready isnt one? what should i do

Comment: Ok, so keep following that tutorial through pages 3 and 4 where it will have you create a php.ini file and restart apache.  Then you can test your php installation.